# How to handle recursion in FIX?

Tags: fix-protocol

Imagine a situation where you need to have recursive data structures, like trees, represented in a FIX message. How would you do that?

I could represent a data structure in JSON like this:

```
{
  {
    "name": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "3",
    "chains": [
      [
        {
          "name": "a"
        },
        {
          "name": "c",
          "chains": [
            {
              "name": "x"
            },
          ]
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "name": "A"
        },
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

How could I represent this in FIX?

---

I'm going to propose a solution here.

Standard FIX tag numbers are ignored.

Tags:

- 1 = Name
- 3 = NumberOfNodes
- 4 = NumberOfChains

Components:

- Node: Name (1) tag is required and Chains component is optional
- Chains: NumberOfChains (4) is required and at least one Chain is required
- Chain: NumberOfNodes (3) is required and at least one Node is required

Lines starting with # are comment and are not part of the actual message.
New lines are tag delimiters.

```
# start of level 0
3=2
1=1
1=3
start of level 1
4=2
3=2
1=a
1=c
# start of level 2
4=1
3=1
1=x
# end of level 2
3=1
1=A
# end of level 1
# end of level 0
```

Please comment if this is valid FIX or not and whether there is a better way to express this in FIX.

Comment: this is what components and repeating groups do, have you read the spec?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the standard FIX dictionary never recurses.  Because that would be insane.

Comment: @MD-Tech I'm using components and repeating groups here in the example and I have read the specs. It is not clear to me how to do recursion with them though.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier I have not found any references about that either. Googling "fix protocol recursion" or "fix protocol recurse" does not yield anything useful. Using FIX for recursion seems insane but if there is one wants to extend FIX for something more general purpose with custom message types then such a need may arise. It may be simplest solution in some cases to stick to FIX even when recursion is needed when all the other messaging is already in FIX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good reason to have a recursive segment in a FIX message.  Why would any financial info transmission need to go infinitely deep?

You can't find any information about it because there aren't any parties in the traditional FIX userbase who would want that.

I suppose you could customize your FIX data dictionary to make a repeating group contain itself.  I suspect that such a DD would crash the code generators of at least one (if not all) of the QuickFIX ports, as they probably aren't checking for such insanity (and thus will keep creating recursive structures in your memory until they blow it).